# Divide a rectangle into four triangles mathematically and determinate the pointer location

Tags: javascript, html, math, geometry

Looking at the picture below, a rectangle has been divided into four triangles and named top, right, bottom, and left.

The objective is to determine the pointer location based on the triangle boundaries, so the return value should be top, right, bottom, left.

[image]

One way to determine the pointer location is to add four divs to the box and use `elementFromPoint` to determine the pointer location. ([here is the example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/divide-div-into-four-triangle-wm4xi?file=/index.html:110-137))

However, it feels like a hacky solution, Surely there must be a more elegant way to do this mathematically without additional divs.

Following variables are known:

div dimantion:

width: 100px;
height: 50px;

Pointer Location:

x: 40px
y: 15px

Any suggestion?

Comment: In the question you state `determine the pointer location based on the triangle boundaries` but in the image, the pointer position is based on the ' container ' boundaries, not the triangle boundaries. Also, please share what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: You can calculate the crossover point (it's half the X/Y of the div) and then you can work out if some point is inside that triangle (topleft, topright, crossover) by summing the areas formed by the triangles that use the point and 2 of the outer triangle points. If the sum is the same, it is within. if it is not it is outside : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSPYO.png -> areas a+b+c = outer area if p is within

Comment: @CaiusJard interesting solution will try it shortly, tnx

Comment: @MihaiT i have a problem with the internet connection but have managed to add my solution, please have a look at it. tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the point's coordinates are x and y, you can calculate the y values of the two diagonals at x, and compare y to them:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} x X coordinate of the point
 * @param {number} y Y coordinate of the point
 * @param {number} w Width of the rectangle
 * @param {number} h Height of the rectangle
 * @returns {-1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3} -1 = Outside, 0 = Left, 1 = Right, 2 = Top, 3 = Bottom
 */
function pointInRectanglePart(x, y, w, h) {
  const y1 = h * x / w; // y of 1st diagonal at x
  const y2 = h - y1; // y of 2nd diagonal at x
  return (
    x < 0 || w <= x || y < 0 || h <= y ? -1 :
    y < y1 ? (y < y2 ? 2 : 1) : (y < y2 ? 0 : 3)
  );
}
```

Note that this function returns number codes for the four triangles (defined in the comment above the function) and returns -1 if the point is outside the rectangle.

[JSFiddle test page](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/p4uz0w98/)